# Errors with plotly_click in R Plotly version 4.9.0. Is there a bug in the new version?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

**Update 3: new test app with dropdownbutton issue**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)
library(shinyWidgets)

rm(list = ls(), envir = environment()) ## to prevent cross over from old runs

testData = data.frame(day = sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 24), frequency = sample(1:5, 24, replace = T ), datecoloring = sample(1:2, 24, replace = T ))
testData$dayPOSIXct <- as.POSIXct(testData$day)

dateRangeMin <- min(testData$day)
dateRangeMax <- max(testData$day)




  ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar( 
      menuItem("Testpage", tabName = "Testpage", icon = icon("home"))
                      ),
    dashboardBody( 
      tabItems(
        # 1) Test Tab ---------------------------------------------------------------

        tabItem(tabName = "Testpage",
            actionButton(inputId = 'Load', label = 'Data'),
            dropdownButton(inputId= "TestButton", label = NULL,
              plotlyOutput('testplot', width = 700, height = 500),
              icon = icon("list-alt"), 
              tooltip = tooltipOptions(title = "Click to open and render the plot"), width = "1670px")

        )
      )
      ),
    title = "Dashboard example"
  )


server <- function(input, output,session) {

  values <- reactiveValues()

  observeEvent(input$Load, { 
    values$testData <- testData
  })

  output$testplot <- renderPlotly({
    req(values$testData)
    p <-  plot_ly(data = values$testData, source = 'testplot',
                  color  = as.factor(values$testData$datecoloring), colors = c('#339fff', '#eaf5ff'),
                  opacity= 0.5, showlegend = T,
                  marker = list(line = list(width = 2, color = '#0000ff')),
                  hoverinfo = "text",
                  text = ~paste('Files:', values$testData$frequency, '<br>Date:', format(values$testData$day, format = '%Y-%m-%d'), sep = ' '))%>%
      add_bars( x = ~dayPOSIXct, y =  ~frequency,   type = "bar", width = 36000000
      )

    p
  })

  relayout_data <- reactive({
    req(values$testData)
    event_data("plotly_relayout", source = "testplot")
  })

  observeEvent(relayout_data(),{
    print(relayout_data())
  })  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**UPDATE 2:** the issue can indeed be circumvented with approaches that properly use `req()` with or without separating the observing of the event_data from the code that does something with the event_data. such as:

```
relayout_data <- reactive({
req(values$testData)
event_data("plotly_relayout", source = "testplot")


 })

  observeEvent(relayout_data(),{
    print(relayout_data())
  })
```

However, this seems not to provide a solution for situations where the plot is inside i.e. a dropdownbutton panel or other tab/page of a shiny App. After the needed data for the plot is loaded, req() is met and the code will fire, yet the plot is still not rendered as it is not in the current screen.

**UPDATE: the issue is also reported on github, no real solution yet**
https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1528

**Original question / post:**

Today I updated all my packages in R and suddenly I got a long list of errors coming from the new plotly version 4.9.0 in R with my R shiny App.

all these errors refer to `plotly_relayout`, `plotly_click` etc.

> Warning: The 'plotly_relayout' event tied a source ID of
>   'DateRangeHisto' is not registered. In order to obtain this event
>   data, please add `event_register(p, 'plotly_relayout')` to the plot
>   (`p`) that you wish to obtain event data from.

I tried to add the event_register in various ways, but no effect. I suppose there is a bug in the new version?

Here is a nonsense dummy app that produces the bug with 
plotly 4.9.0
and all packages updated.

**UPDATE: the error seems to happen when data is not available for the plot**
despite the `req()` inside the `plot_ly` block, the `event_data` causes an error. This did not happen with the previous versions of plotly..... so, how to get rid of this is now the question

```
    library(shiny)
    library(plotly)



rm(list = ls(), envir = environment()) ## to prevent cross over from old runs

testData = data.frame(day = sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 24), frequency = sample(1:5, 24, replace = T ), datecoloring = sample(1:2, 24, replace = T ))
testData$dayPOSIXct <- as.POSIXct(testData$day)

dateRangeMin <- min(testData$day)
dateRangeMax <- max(testData$day)
if(!require('shiny')){ install.packages('shiny', dependencies=TRUE)}
if(!require('shinyWidgets')){ install.packages('shinyWidgets', dependencies=TRUE)}
if(!require('plotly')){ install.packages('plotly', dependencies=TRUE)}
if(!require('htmlwidgets')){ install.packages('htmlwidgets')}


ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton(inputId = 'Load', label = 'Data'),
  plotlyOutput('testplot', width = 700, height = 500)

)


server <- function(input, output,session) {

  values <- reactiveValues()

  observeEvent(input$Load, { 
    values$testData <- testData
    })

  output$testplot <- renderPlotly({ 
    req(values$testData)
    p <-  plot_ly(data = values$testData, source = 'testplot',
                  color  = as.factor(values$testData$datecoloring), colors = c('#339fff', '#eaf5ff'),
                  opacity= 0.5, showlegend = T,
                  marker = list(line = list(width = 2, color = '#0000ff')),
                  hoverinfo = "text",
                  text = ~paste('Files:', values$testData$frequency, '<br>Date:', format(values$testData$day, format = '%Y-%m-%d'), sep = ' '))%>%
      add_bars( x = ~dayPOSIXct, y =  ~frequency,   type = "bar", width = 36000000
      )
    p
  })

  observeEvent(event_data("plotly_relayout", source = "testplot"),{
    #any code here, doesn't matter, bug happens already
  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Session info

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252  LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Netherlands.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] plotly_4.9.0  ggplot2_3.1.1 shiny_1.3.2  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1         pillar_1.4.0       compiler_3.5.3     later_0.8.0        colourpicker_1.0.3 plyr_1.8.4         shinyjs_1.0        tools_3.5.3        digest_0.6.19      viridisLite_0.3.0 
[11] jsonlite_1.6       tibble_2.1.1       gtable_0.3.0       pkgconfig_2.0.2    rlang_0.3.4        rstudioapi_0.10    crosstalk_1.0.0    yaml_2.2.0         httr_1.4.0         withr_2.1.2       
[21] dplyr_0.8.1        htmlwidgets_1.3    grid_3.5.3         DT_0.6             tidyselect_0.2.5   glue_1.3.1         data.table_1.12.2  R6_2.4.0           tidyr_0.8.3        purrr_0.3.2       
[31] magrittr_1.5       scales_1.0.0       promises_1.0.1     htmltools_0.3.6    assertthat_0.2.1   mime_0.6           xtable_1.8-4       colorspace_1.4-1   httpuv_1.5.1       miniUI_0.1.1.1    
[41] lazyeval_0.2.2     munsell_0.5.0      crayon_1.3.4
```

Comment: Your `source` argument should be `"testplot"` not `"DateRangeHisto"`?

Comment: sorry, typo in building the testapp. Will correct it. Error is the same though

Comment: On my machine, also using `plotly_4.9.0` the error isn't shown after correcting the `source`

Comment: Can you recreate it now? I think I have come a step closer to the source of the errors. See update. It seems to happen to plots that require data which is not present yet at the loading of the app

Comment: That makes sense, the observer is trying to access the `event_data` before the plot is created (blocked by `req()`).

Comment: yeah but before 4.9.0 this didn't happen. The observer simply ignored the missing event_data..... Should not be needed to write a difficult solution now to stop this from crashing my apps

Comment: Instead of using `req` you could do `if(is.null(values$testData)){ p <- plotly_empty(source = "testplot) } else { ...... }`. But I'm not sure I understand the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure which part you do not understand Stefane, so it's hard to explain. (also hard to build a reprocible example that throws errors as much as my real app. The demo can be solved with just a require it seems, but my real app isn't satisfied with that and keeps tossing out the errors as apparently it

Comment: See last comment below the other answer too

Comment: Could you please provide us with the described `dropdownbutton` issue in your example code? I'd be interested to see this special situation.

Comment: New example is up, and a solution I found is using this: 
  outputOptions(output, "testplot", suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)
The downside is that this might slow the app a bit if it is a scatterplot with 10k points that keeps updating whenever there is a change even when we don't look at it.....

Comment: @Mark thanks for all the work around this post. I am as well struggling with this issue now. I tried reproducing your test program from UPDATE3 and with plotly version 4.10 what before was an annoying warning, has now become a VERY ANNOYING ERROR. When reproducing your example I get "Error: (converted from warning) The 'plotly_relayout' event tied a source ID of 'testplot' is not registered." Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `observeEvent` is trying to access the `event_data` before the plot is rendered. You can work around this behaviour by using `req()` also for your `event_data()`. Plotly 4.9.0 indeed seems to be more strict about this.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)
library(shinyWidgets)

rm(list = ls(), envir = environment()) ## to prevent cross over from old runs

testData = data.frame(day = sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 24), frequency = sample(1:5, 24, replace = T ), datecoloring = sample(1:2, 24, replace = T ))
testData$dayPOSIXct <- as.POSIXct(testData$day)

dateRangeMin <- min(testData$day)
dateRangeMax <- max(testData$day)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Testpage", tabName = "Testpage", icon = icon("home"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody( 
    tabItems(
      # 1) Test Tab ---------------------------------------------------------------

      tabItem(tabName = "Testpage",
              actionButton(inputId = 'Load', label = 'Data'),
              dropdownButton(inputId = "TestButton", label = NULL,
                             plotlyOutput('testplot', width = 700, height = 500),
                             icon = icon("list-alt"), 
                             tooltip = tooltipOptions(title = "Click to open and render the plot"), width = "1670px")

      )
    )
  ),
  title = "Dashboard example"
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # output$testplot <- renderPlotly({plot_ly(data.frame(NULL), source = 'testplot')})

  values <- reactiveValues()

  observeEvent(input$Load, {
    values$testData <- testData
  })

  output$testplot <- renderPlotly({
    req(values$testData)
    p <-  plot_ly(data = values$testData, source = 'testplot',
                  color  = as.factor(values$testData$datecoloring), colors = c('#339fff', '#eaf5ff'),
                  opacity= 0.5, showlegend = T,
                  marker = list(line = list(width = 2, color = '#0000ff')),
                  hoverinfo = "text",
                  text = ~paste('Files:', values$testData$frequency, '<br>Date:', format(values$testData$day, format = '%Y-%m-%d'), sep = ' '))%>%
      add_bars( x = ~dayPOSIXct, y =  ~frequency,   type = "bar", width = 36000000)
    p 
  })

  relayout_data <- reactive({
    req(values$testData)
    req(input$TestButton_state)
    event_data("plotly_relayout", source = "testplot")
  })

  observeEvent(relayout_data(),{
    print(relayout_data())
  })  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: doesn't print again if you apply zoom (i.e. relayout) it seems

Comment: it helps a bit this solution, but in my real app it still gives errors even when I use the req(). Eventhough the plot and the event_data now have the same req() line, it seems the event_data still throws out errors until the plot is actually on my screen (many of them are in dropdowns or on tabItem pages.

Comment: That's strange - did you replace `observeEvent` with `observe` as I did? Otherwise I'd give @StéphaneLaurent's comment a try and always create a empty plot if no data is available.

Comment: I did replace that indeed and am puzzled what makes it still throw the errors until the plot is actually called on screen.  I ALSO found that the new plotly doesnt like to create plots anymore with zero data points within the axis range. Before the actual data is present I fed a dummy df into the plot function that plots 1 point in the negative range, ie outside the plot scale, which gave nice empty plot objects but with 4.9.0 I now get blank space and a plot title plus my whole shiny app starts acting extremely slow if I visited a page with such a dummy plot

Comment: Just updated to your latest example. Not sure, if this is an option for you, but if you trigger getting the data also using the `dropdownButton` instead of your "Load"-button, the warning is gone. You could use `once = TRUE` to stop refreshing the data on every button click. (Please see my edit).

Comment: My data is coming from other processes in the real world of course, but perhaps I could add a 'values$HasThisBeenOpened' to the app, and then turn it into T when the dropdownbutton is opened (its blocked anyway till there is data), and then add req(values$HasThisBeenOpened) to the reactive

Comment: Exactly, that would be an alternative to using `outputOptions(output, "testplot", suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)`, maybe it helps regarding performance.

Comment: @Mark, please see another edit and `?dropdownButton`: It is possible to know if a dropdown is open or closed server-side with input$<inputId>_state. If you `req()` that for your `relayout_data` it works as I'd expect.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this same issue, and a possible approach to avoid the warning is to start the `observeEvent` that watches `event_data` in a suspended state with `suspended = TRUE`, e.g.

```
observer <- observeEvent(event_data("plotly_relayout", source = "testplot"), suspended = TRUE, {
        print(event_data("plotly_relayout", source = "testplot"))
      })
```

Then start observing only after the plot is created by adding `observer$resume()` inside `renderPlotly` after defining the plot object `p`.

---

The following minimal shiny-app illustrates this by watching `event_data("plotly_click")` for a plot inside `uiOutput` that is only available after the `actionButton` and the `checkbox` have been selected:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(

    ## button
    actionButton("load", label = "New data"),
    ## checkbox
    checkboxInput("show", label = "Show plot"),
    ## plot 
    uiOutput("plot_ui"),
    ## click events
    tableOutput("clicked")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  ## reactive values
  r <- reactiveValues(
      data = NULL,
      suspended = TRUE,
      clicked = NULL
  )

  ## load data 
  observeEvent(input$load, { 
        r$data <- data.frame(x= 1:100, y = rnorm(100))
      })

  ## show plot only if checkbox is selected
  output$plot_ui <- renderUI({
        req(input$show)
        plotlyOutput("plot") 
      })

  ## plotly plot
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
        req(r$data)
        p <- plot_ly(data = r$data, x = ~x, y = ~y, mode = "markers", type = "scatter", source = "plot")
        ## resume observer only if suspended 
        if(r$suspended) {
          observer$resume()
          r$suspended <- FALSE
        }
        return(p)
      })

  ## observe click events
  observer <- observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click", source = "plot"), suspended = TRUE, {
        r$clicked <- rbind(r$clicked, event_data("plotly_click", source = "plot"))
      })  

  ## display clicked points
  output$clicked <- renderTable(
      r$clicked
  )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

NB: the reactive value `r$suspended` ensures that `observer$resume()` is called only if the observer's state was actually suspended.